# height issue with AngularSlideables

Tags: angularjs

I'm using AngularSlideables:

https://github.com/EricWVGG/AngularSlideables

I'm having a problem where the slider isn't working on chrome.  If I manually set the height it works, but I have dynamic content so I can't set a fixed value.

Here's my code:

```
 .directive('slideable', function () {
    return {
    restrict:'C',
    compile: function (element, attr) {
        // wrap tag
        var contents = element.html();

        /*
            I need to get the height of the contents variable above so that I can set it within element.html, like so:
            <div class="slideable_content" style="margin:0 !important; padding:0 !important; height: contents.height" >
        */

       // var height = element.html().prop('offsetHeight');

        element.html('<div class="slideable_content" style="margin:0 !important; padding:0 !important;" >' + contents +  '</div>');

        return function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
            // default properties
            attrs.duration = (!attrs.duration) ? '1s' : attrs.duration;
            attrs.easing = (!attrs.easing) ? 'ease-in-out' : attrs.easing;
            element.css({
                'overflow': 'hidden',
                'height': '0px',
              //  'max-height' : '0';
                //'height': '1500px',
               // 'height': content.scrollHeight,
                'transitionProperty': 'height',
                'transitionDuration': attrs.duration,
                'transitionTimingFunction': attrs.easing
            });
        };
    }
};
})
```

Any ideas how I can get this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with this is not the above code.  There is another directive.

For some reason Chrome doesn't like doing this:

```
var content = target.querySelector('.slideable_content');
    target.style.height = content.scrollHeight + 'px';
```

This worked instead:

```
var target = document.querySelector(attrs.slideToggle);
target.style.height = target.scrollHeight + 'px';
```